# Why does copying an array into another array change the original array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I copy a 2D array into a different temporary array, it changes my original when I perform operations on the temporary.

**Here is a part of my code to show what I mean:**

```
public int getPossibleMoves(int color, int turn) {
  int x = 0;
  int blankI;
  blankI = -1;
  int pBoard[][];
  pBoard = new int[board.length][board.length];
  System.arraycopy(board, 0, pBoard, 0, board.length);

  //if its the first turn and color is black, then there are four possible moves
  if(turn == 0 && color == BLACK) {       
    pBoard[0][0] = BLANK;
    current.addChild(pBoard);
    current.children.get(x).setParent(current);
    System.arraycopy(board, 0, pBoard, 0, board.length);
    x++;

    pBoard[pBoard.length-1][pBoard.length-1] = BLANK;
    current.addChild(pBoard);
    current.children.get(x).setParent(current);
    System.arraycopy(board, 0, pBoard, 0, board.length);
    x++;

    pBoard[pBoard.length/2][pBoard.length/2] = BLANK;
    current.addChild(pBoard);
    current.children.get(x).setParent(current);
    System.arraycopy(board, 0, pBoard, 0, board.length);
    x++;

    pBoard[(pBoard.length/2)-1][(pBoard.length/2)-1] = BLANK;
    current.addChild(pBoard);
    current.children.get(x).setParent(current);
    System.arraycopy(board, 0, pBoard, 0, board.length);
    x++;
  }
```

On the line that says `pBoard[0][0] = BLANK;` and the similar ones, it changes board as well as `pBoard` and I need board to stay the same for my program to work correctly.

I have found an answer similar to this, which is where I got the idea to use `System.arraycopy()` instead of `pBoard = board`. The `System.arraycopy()` works in a different program that I used it in, but not in this one.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**One more thing:**
This is part of a homework assignment. However, solving this small issue will not even bring me close to the final product that I need. This is just a tiny chunk of my code so far, but I need to get past this to move on.

Comment: Looks like you are copying references and not object. This is shallow copying

Comment: `int`s are primitives and not "copied by reference"

Comment: I doubt very much that this code modifies `board` in any way, perhaps somewhere else in your code?

Comment: I used the netbeans debugger and it changes both pBoard and board when it goes through the pBoard[0][0] = BLANK; line.  BLANK = -1 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a deep copy.

Instead of:

```
pBoard = new int[board.length][board.length];
System.arraycopy(board, 0, pBoard, 0, board.length);
```

Try:

```
pBoard = new int[board.length][];
for ( int i = 0; i < pBoard.length; i++ ) {
  pBoard[i] = new int[board[i].length];
  System.arraycopy(board[i], 0, pBoard[i], 0, board[i].length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I did something similar to that and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`int board[][]` is array of references to arrays of type `int[]`. `System.arraycopy(board, 0, pBoard, 0, board.length)` copies the array of references but not the referenced arrays, which now are accessible in two ways. To make deep copy you have to make copies of the referenced one-dimensional arrays also. Note, to make a copy of an array you can use `array.clone()`. Consider also to use a one-dimensional array of size N*N with access `array[x+N*y]`.