# Multidimensional Array Output?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

basically, the output for the code below is 2. Could someone explain to me why that is so? Thank you so much :).

```
int[][] x = {{3,1,4},{1,5,9}};
int[] y = {2,6,7};
y = x[1];
y[1] = 1;
System.out.println (x[0][1] + x[1][1]);
```

Comment: @Gendarme I checked aha the output is like that.

Comment: @JCole `1 + 1 = 2` This is some basic Java...

Comment: This is because you're assigning `int[] y` to be `int[][] x` second row. So whatever you do to `y` will also occur to `x`. You want to use `Array.clone()` or `Array.copy()` so you don't run into this issue.

Comment: Look at this question: [Why does copying an array into another array change the original array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837356/why-does-copying-an-array-into-another-array-change-the-original-array)

Comment: Also take a look at this question: [why is my array updated even when I don't choose to update it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834815/why-is-my-array-updated-even-when-i-dont-choose-to-update-it)

Comment: Is there a problem here, or are you just trying to understand array lookups?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that both y and x[1] reference the same array. See the comments below for more information.

```
int[][] x = {{3,1,4},{1,5,9}}; // x[0] references an array {3,1,4}; x[1] references an array {1,5,9}
int[] y = {2,6,7}; // You create the array {2,6,7} assigning its reference to y
y = x[1]; // While y was referencing the array {2,6,7} you overwrite this reference by the reference stored at x[1]. This reference is pointing at the array {1,5,9}. So now both y and x[1] are pointing to (or referring to in Java slang) the same array!
y[1] = 1; // So now you are changing the array {1,5,9} to {1,1,9} (y[1] is the same as x[1][1]
System.out.println (x[0][1] + x[1][1]); // x[0][1] (meaning the second value from the first array (referenced by x), which value is 1.) x[1][1]  (meaning the second value from the second array, which value is also 1.) So 1 + 1 is in fact 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I start explaining, keep this in mind: *An int is a primitive type; an array is an object.*

Take a look at this simple code:

```
int[] x = {1,2,3};
int y = x[0];
y = 5;
System.out.print(x[0]);
```

the output is `1` and *not* `5` for the following reason:

`y` is being assigned *the value of* `x[0]`, essentially getting a copy of it. It does not point to `x[0]` so any future changes to `y` do not apply to `x`.

---

In your situation with two-dimensional arrays, you have the following code:

```
int[][] x = {{3,1,4},{1,5,9}};
int[] y = {2,6,7};
y = x[1];
y[1] = 1;
System.out.println (x[0][1] + x[1][1]);
```

The essential difference here is the following:

`y` is being assigned *the value of the reference of* `x[1]`, which here too is a copy, but since it is a reference (because `x[1]` is an array) it does not really matter, cause the original and the copy both point to the same object. Whether you use `y` or `x[1]` you are referring to the same object, even though these are two different references.

Answer (score 1):

Because variables containing arrays in java (like other objects) are just references to these objects

In more details:

**At start:**

- x[0] is equal to {3, 1, 4}
- x[1] is equal to {1, 5, 9}
- y is equal to {2, 6, 7}

This is easy.

**Then**

When we do y = x[1], we don't change the values of y. Instead, what happens is that y now **points to** x[1]

In memory, we have somewhere the array {1, 5, 9} and two variables are looking there (x[1] and y). This also means that in memory, we still have somewhere the array {2, 6, 7} but no variable are looking at (pointing at) it (since y changed  to look at the same location as x[1]). In java, the garbage collector automatically finds what memory location aren't used anymore and cleans the memory

**So finally**

Changing either x[0] or y will access the same place in memory so the value will change for both variables. doing

```
y[1] = 1;
```

is exactly the same as doing

```
x[1][1] = 1;
```

When doing so, we change the array and it becomes {1, 1, 9}

So `x[0][1] + x[1][1]` is equal to `1+1`

This will occure all the time when you program, since this is the same behaviour for all Objects.

**Side note** You will see that many people argue on the exact terminology when speaking of references in Java. Java does not pass by reference in the same way as in c++. What you shoud remember for a start is how variables behave when assigned to arrays or objects

Answer (score 1):

Our starting position is

```
int[][] x = {{3,1,4},{1,5,9}};
int[] y = {2,6,7};
```

which can be shown as

```
x →  {  [0]     ,      [1]     }
         ↓              ↓         // each 1D array like {3,1,4} can be also shown as  
         {3,1,4}        {1,5,9}   //  { [0] [1] [2] }
                                  //     ↓   ↓   ↓
y →  {2,6,7}                      //     3   1   4    but I skipped that for simplicity
```

(since any 2D array in Java is simply 1D array of other 1D arrays).

When we execute `y = x[1];` `y` will now be reference to ***same array*** which is stored in `x[1]` (it is not copy of original array with same elements, it is same array).

So situation bow is similar to

```
x →  {  [0]     ,      [1]     }
         ↓              ↓
         {3,1,4}        {1,5,9}
                        ↑
y ──────────────────────┘
```

This means that we can change that same array via two references `y` and `x[1]` and each change can be also seen via other reference.

So if we do

```
y[1] = 1;
```

it will also affect array held by `x[1]` like

```
x →  {   [0]     ,    [1]     }
          ↓            ↓
          {3,1,4}      {1,1,9}
                       ↑  └─changed
y ─────────────────────┘
```

Now `x` looks like `{{3,1,4},{1,1,9}};`.

```
x → {    
├[0] → {  
│ ├─[0] → 3 
│ ├─[1] → 1 //x[0][1]
│ └─[2] → 4
│      } 
└[1] → {  
  ├─[0] → 1 
  ├─[1] → 1 //x[1][1]
  └─[2] → 9
       }
    }
```

So since `x[0][1] = 1` and `x[1][1]=1` their sum is `2`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense now, I got confused when it said x[0][1]. It is more clear now thank you so much :). Gendarme, Robert, Toaster and Pshemo :).

Answer (score 1):

this why :

```
    int[][] x = {{3,1,4},{1,5,9}};
    int[] y = {2,6,7};
    y = x[1]; //{1, 5, 9}
    y[1] = 1; //{1, 1, 9}
    System.out.println (x[0][1]/* {3,*1*,4} */ + x[1][1] /* {1, *1*, 9} */);
```

in **Java** when you assign array like these `y = x[1];` or pass *array* any way possible (to method for example) you actually pass copy of `reference` `x[1]` array to another one, array `y` have same reference as `x` to `GC` where array exsis and when you change the value `y[1]`

```
y[1] = 1; //{1, 1, 9}
```

you actually change value are share it between `y[1]` and `x[1][1]`